Restriction rule in Object manager is not working
I'm trying to enforce a rule where user can see their own records only whereas admin can see all records by all users.
I have created restriction rule using the user title.
Included the screenshot of the rule for reference
(utility provider here is a user)

I think you can just leverage by setting org-wide-default to private, to achieve this.

Hi Prem, But I'm doing this for people inside the same org. One user act as a provider and other user acts as a consumer. So provider must see all the consumers data, but each consumer must have access to their own data only.
